# KAFKA SINK CONNECT: WARN Bulk request 167 failed. Retrying request

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a data process with Input Topic,Kafka Stream and Output Topic connected to a sink connect for Elasticsearch.

At the beginning of this operation, the data ingestion is done satisfactorily, but when the process has been running for a longer time, Elasticsearch ingestion from connector starts to fail.
I have been checking all the Workers logs and I get the following message which I suspect may be the reason:

```
    [2021-10-21 11:22:14,246] WARN Bulk request 168 failed. Retrying request. (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient:335)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 3,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-643 [ACTIVE]
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:492)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:213)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

[2021-10-21 11:27:23,858] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-ElasticsearchSinkConnector-topic01-0, groupId=connect-ElasticsearchSinkConnector-topic01] Member connector-consumer-ElasticsearchSinkConnector-topic01-0-41b68d34-0f00-4887-b54e-79561fffb5e5 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator kafka1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1042)
```

I have tried to change the connector configuration, but I don't understand the main reason for this problem to fix it.

Connector Configuration:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
connection.password=xxxxx
topics=output_topic
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
connection.username=user-x
name=ElasticsearchSinkConnector-output_topic
connection.url=xxxxxxx
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.ignore=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
schema.ignore=true
```

Is it possible that the Bulk Warn causes a loss of data?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding

```
"flush.timeout.ms": 30000
```